# How to get the react component instance corresponding to event.target element in a click handler?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my react component class

```
class TestInstance extends React.Component {
    onClick(e) {
        //When the user clicks in the button, 
        //I need to read the custom-id property here
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Wrapper onClickCapture={this.onClick}>
                <div>
                    <button custom-data={{test: 'test data'}}>Click Me</button>
                </div>
            </Wrapper>
        );
    }
}
```

Here I'm listening to all click events that happen under the wrapper node. Whenever a click happens, I need to find out the react component instance associated with `e.target` and that instance's value for its `custom-data` prop. There will be multiple such children with different values for `custom-data` prop. Whenever such an element is clicked, I want to extract that element's value for its `custom-data` prop an do some stuff. What is the best way to do this in reactjs? One way would be to navigate the entire children tree and comapring the `e.target` instance for identity with the DOM elements for each of the children. I also found that `e._targetInst._currentElement.props` gives me the value of the props. But I don't know how reliable these undocumented variables are. Is there any documented solution for this? Basically I'm looking for something that gives me the opposite effect of ReactDOM.findDOMNode. I already have a DOM node and I need the React Element associated with that.

Comment: We're missing some information here. In your example code, the value of the `custom-id` prop is always going to be `"btn"`, unless some code that you haven't shared is changing that value. What are we missing?

Comment: @Jordan I just gave this as an example.. There will be a number of other children with different values for `custom-id` attribute. When any of them are clicked, I want to extract the value of their `custom-id` attribute and do some stuff with it.

Comment: How does `Wrapper` listen for all click events on its children?

Comment: *How* does `Wrapper` listen for all click events on its children?

Comment: It is attached in capture mode. So every event will reach there first before filtering down to its children.

Comment: The easiest solution by far is to just call the prop `data-custom-id` instead of `custom-id` so it stays in the DOM and you can just call `evt.target.getAttribute('data-custom-id')`;

Comment: @Jordan I had already tried that. React does not support custom data attributes

Comment: "React supports all `data-*` and `aria-*` attributes as well as these attributes..." https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html#all-supported-html-attributes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132946/discussion-between-jophin-joseph-and-jordan).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments above, this is much easier if you call the prop `data-custom-id` instead of `custom-id`. That way it will be rendered as a DOM attribute and you can get its value by calling `e.target.getAttribute('data-custom-id')`. You can see it working in the below snippet. (Since you didn't show us the code for the Wrapper component I took a guess at an implementation.)

```js
class Wrapper extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.refs.wrap.addEventListener('click', this.props.onClickCapture, true);
  }
  componentDidUnmount() {
    this.refs.wrap.removeEventListener('click', this.props.onClickCapture);
  }
  render() {
    return <div ref="wrap">{this.props.children}</div>;
  }
}

class TestInstance extends React.Component {
  onClick(e) {
    console.log('Clicked %s', e.target.getAttribute('data-custom-id'));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Wrapper onClickCapture={this.onClick}>
        <div>
          <button data-custom-id="btn-1">Button 1</button>
          <button data-custom-id="btn-2">Button 2</button>
        </div>
      </Wrapper>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TestInstance/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"/>
```

Comment: Any idea how to do this had `custom-id` been a JSON object(other than stringifying it)?

Comment: There are a few ways you could do it, but none of them is especially clean. I would instead reconsider the way you're handling the `click` events. Rather than a single event listener, I would give each button its own `onClick`, e.g. `<button onClick={e => this.props.onClick(e, 'btn-1')}>`.

Answer (score -1):

Save a ref to it and check that e.target is the same as ref

```
class TestInstance extends React.Component {
    element = null;

    onClick(e) {
        //When the user clicks in the button, 
        //I need to read the custom-id property here
        if (e.target === ReactDOM.findDOMNode(element)) {
          // get custom id here
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Wrapper onClickCapture={this.onClick}>
                <div>
                    <button ref={e => this.element = e} custom-id="btn">Click Me</button>
                </div>
            </Wrapper>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I have multiple(about 20-30) nodes with `custom-id`. This approach will require that manu number of variables to store refs. And for every click I'll have to check against the entire set

Answer (score -1):

```js
class Wrapper extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
       <button onClick = {()=>this.props.onCapture({'id':'1','name':'btn-1'})}>Button 1</button>
       <button onClick = {()=>this.props.onCapture({'id':'2','name':'btn-2'})}>Button 2</button>
        </div>
    )
  }
}

class TestInstance extends React.Component {
  onClick(expr) {
    console.log(expr);
    //console.log('Clicked %s', e);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Wrapper onCapture={this.onClick}/>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TestInstance/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root" />
```

Comment: You can assign event handler to each button and drop your JSON as a param to function

Comment: This is just event handling.. This is not what I'm looking for